# Netsuite - Getting Started with ODBC Queries

Tags: jquery, sql, odbc, netsuite

I have the ODBC setup on windows using this...

https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38988

Seems like it is setup and I entered the system DSN info ok...

Now, I need to know how I can use it to run some SQL queries on windows 10. Is there a windows App that can run SQL queries using this Netsuite ODBC connection? Or, how else can I run Netsuite queries with this ODBC connect - php or something else?

NEW UPDATE ISSUE: when I tried to test the netsuite system DSN connection - it failed. error = You do not have permission to use SuiteAnalytics: Connect service.

I was told I DO have permission.

Q: So what do I need to make sure this is setup in netsuite for me to use?

Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) or you can write your own app that hits the ODBC connection.  I like python / ipython / jupyter, so I use that with pyodbc to send queries via the ODBC driver.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions.